# Creating foreign key between 2 tables

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Ok, so it's like this. I have 2 tables in phpmyadmin. One is for personal details and the other is for login information. Both tables have `AccountID`, so I tried using foreign key constraints to connect the tables. After I did that it seems like I cannot update the table with new data. Before the constraint, updating the tables worked fine.

What I'm trying to do is store user login info and personal info in these table. Then whenever the user wants to delete their current account, the personal details and login details of are deleted from both tables or when they wanted to search for their login and personal info the search engine can search from both tables with `AccountID`.

so far.i have make 2 new tables.1 table which is personal information have 'AccountID'[A_I][PRIMARY] and 'loginID'.another table is login info.it has 'loginID'[A_i][PRIMARY]

i already make the 'loginID' at personal info and index but i cannot assign foreign key constraint for it bcause it did not detect 'loginID' in personal info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AccountId should be a primary key in one table say Personal Info table.
This AccountId should be the foreign key in another table (Login) and make sure you set on Delete Cascade and on Update Cascade.
So in this structure, when personal info is deleted, its corresponding record in the login table will be automatically deleted.

```html
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `stacktest`.`personal_info`;
CREATE TABLE  `stacktest`.`personal_info` (
  `account_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `age` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`account_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `stacktest`.`login_info`;
CREATE TABLE  `stacktest`.`login_info` (
  `loginId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`loginId`),
  KEY `FK_login_info_1` (`account_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_login_info_1` FOREIGN KEY (`account_id`) REFERENCES `personal_info` (`account_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Above is the way how the 2 tables should be created.
Then insert some values in both table,

**Note** that account_id value has to be same in both the tables.

After that you can fire a delete query like:

delete from personal_info where accound_id=2;

This will delete rows from parent table personal_info and also from child table login_info where account_id is 2

Keeping the account_id as NOT NULL in child table:

```html
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `stacktest`.`login_info`;
CREATE TABLE  `stacktest`.`login_info` (
  `loginId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`loginId`),
  KEY `FK_login_info_1` (`account_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_login_info_1` FOREIGN KEY (`account_id`) REFERENCES `personal_info` (`account_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: @Ashraf: So did you followed my method and achieved what you wanted?

Comment: i got error Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ftm`.`logindetails`, CONSTRAINT `logindetails_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`AccountID`) REFERENCES `personaldetails` (`AccountID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Comment: Error
SQL query:


ALTER TABLE `personaldetails` ADD  FOREIGN KEY (`LoginID`) REFERENCES `ftm`.`logindetails`(`LoginID`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
MySQL said: Documentation

#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ftm`.`#sql-141c_4a8`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-141c_4a8_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`LoginID`) REFERENCES `logindetails` (`LoginID`))

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, you need to keep ON UPDATE and ON DELETE as CASCADE and not RESTRICT.

Your error shows that you have kep RESTRICT.

Comment: Which is your parent table and your child table?

Comment: i tried cascade.same error. parent is personal info and child is login info.ive update what ive done.up there

Comment: @AshrafKamarudin : I have edited my answer to show you how the structure of both tables should be. That will definitely solve your problem.

Comment: why did u make account id null?

Comment: Where did I make account_id null?
In table creation I have set default value for account_id as null for the child table,(You can keep any default value)

and in Parent table account_id being Primary key it cannot be NULL.

Comment: yeah why is it null in child table? it works now if i set it as null in child table.it doesnt work if it is not null.i dont reslly get it..and yes it is not null in parent table

Comment: @AshrafKamarudin: You need to refer to syntax of creating table, primary key and foreign key.
There is no specific reason behind keeping default value as null in the child table. You can also keep it NOT NULL like in parent table.

Comment: I have edited my ANSWER, there in child table I have kept it as NOT NULL.

Comment: You may up vote my answer if you are really appreciate my effort.